# Acid boric preparation

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, boron-family

Is there a simple reaction to yield boric acid ($\ce{H3BO3}$) from boron trifluoride ($\ce{BF3}$)?

Comment: "Quick questions" without elaboration effort are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, hydrolysis of boron trifluoride.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_trifluoride)

$$\ce{4 BF3 + 3 H2O → 3 HBF4 + B(OH)3}$$

The reaction commences with the formation of the aquo adduct, $\ce{H2O−BF3}$, which then loses $\ce{HF}$ leading to formation of the products.

The heavier trihalides do not undergo analogous reactions, possibly due to the low stability of the tetrahedral ions $\ce{BCl4-}$ and $\ce{BBr4-}$.

Comment: I can imagine a less weird way to prepare  boric acid. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid) gives several methods to get boric acid.  The first one uses a relatively common natural source of boron.  Curiously compared with the other answer, boron trifluoride is excluded among the halides.

> Boric acid may be prepared by reacting borax (sodium tetraborate decahydrate) with a mineral acid, such as hydrochloric acid:

$\ce{Na2B4O7·10H2O + 2 HCl → 4 B(OH)3 [or H3BO3] + 2 NaCl + 5 H2O}$

> It is also formed as a by product of hydrolysis of boron trihalides and diborane:[1]

$\ce{B2H6 + 6 H2O → 2 B(OH)3 + 6 H2}$

$\ce{BX3 + 3 H2O → B(OH)3 + 3 HX (X = Cl, Br, I)}$

Upon further review, boron trifluoride can be used to give boric acid as well, as shown in the other answer, but at reduced yield as most of the boron forms $\ce{HBF4}$ instead.  Using a heavier halogen favors all the boron going to boric acid.

Cited reference:

1.
Housecroft, C. E.; Sharpe, A. G. (2008). "Chapter 13: The Group 13 Elements". Inorganic Chemistry (3rd ed.). Pearson. p. 340. ISBN 978-0-13-175553-6.